# game center leaderboard works in sandbox but not release

Tags: iphone, game-center

in sandbox mode leaderboard show up normally, but after it is released via app store, in the game center dashboard, it shows "no leaderboard", and i'm sure at least 3 players had submitted scores.

PS: i didn't wrapper the category with 'com.xxx.xxx', is it ok? cause it works in sandbox.

```
GKScore *uploader = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"board"] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you submit your leaderboards/achievements in iTunesConnect? When you submit your app to the store you also have to select which leaderboards and/or achievements you want to submit with the release of your app. Check your app in iTunesConnect and see if your leaderboards are submitted.

Comment: yes, exactly what u said, how can i resubmit leaderboards? don't tell me i have to submit app again?!